# I am looking for a Python method to Split the list of attributes in a layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a list of attributes in QGIS:

```
[137.0, u'0101S', u'MUNICIPIO', u'28004', 19849.4753178, 22000935.5836, u'\Alamo, El']
```

And I am trying to obtain each element in the list, using pyqgis.

I can't use a simple loop , like

```
for feature in features:
    print feature
```

because it returns the object id.

And if I use this:

```
for feature in features:
print '\n'.join(feature)
```

It returns the following error:

**TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found**

*For example, my aim is:

"value1" = 137.0

"value2" = 0101S

and so on.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by split (assign each value in the list to a incremented variable?), can you expand more what you mean by this?

Comment: I have put : "obtain". I mean, get every value of the list, print it separately, in different lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following?

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feature.attributes()
    for i, j in list(enumerate(attrs)):
        print "value" + str(i + 1) + " = " + str(j)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for the split method... I couldn't manage it. This makes all sense to me

Comment: Most welcome but I would suggest noting @artwork21's answer as the methods described are in my opinion easier to handle ;)

Answer (score 2):

To print the field value you need to provide the field name or index:

**Field Name:**

```
for feature in LYR.getFeatures():
    print feature['myFieldName']
```

**Field Index (first field starts at zero):**

```
for feature in LYR.getFeatures():
    print feature[1] # this is the second field in the table
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. This is a easier method to take into account.Both answers are right.. I can't check both.